# toast notification over 'overlay'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, toastr

I know it's not what toastr (or toast notifs in general) are meant to be used for, but I want to use them as a `modal notification`. My idea is following.

On toast show:

```
toastr.options.onShown = function() { //Create an overlay on the entire page}
```

Overlay:

```
#overlay {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
z-index: 999;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: none;
}
```

And on toast close:

```
toastr.options.onHidden = function() { //make overlay go away }
```

Also, I'm setting timeout of toast to 0 so it won't disappear by itself.

**Question**: I want the toast notification to stay atop the overlay and not behind it as overlay will cover everything. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it right..

Just add

`<div id="overlay"></div>` in body somewhere. Add your required style in stylesheet.

In `toastr.options.onShown` callback, add show overlay `$("#overlay").show();` and in `toastr.options.onHidden` callback hide it.. `$("#overlay").hide();`

Toaster has id `toast-container` which has `z-index` 999999. So in order to move overlay below toastr, set z-index below 999999.. Which is the default case in your stylesheet..

You should be good to go :-)

Comment: Just a heads up, `toast-container` is an id, not a class